# unable to make the model it belongs to also be one that can has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling when it comes to having a joint table, which is also polymorphic and has many to many.

It's setup in a way that a question belongs to a company. A question can belong to a user, group or company through question_participants (polymorphic / joint).

Now I am able to save both users and groups but not company when they select that. I think it has to do with the confusion of it being the owner.

```
# ask question
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController


  def new
    @question = current_user.company.questions.new
  end

  private

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:name, :optional,
                                     user_ids: [], group_ids: [])
  end


# company users belong to
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :questions
end


# questions created by admin
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :question_participants
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :question_participants,
                   source: :questionable, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :groups, through: :question_participants,
                    source: :questionable, source_type: 'Group'
  has_many :companies, through: :question_participants,
                       source: :questionable, source_type: 'Company'
end
```

and the form field:

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :group_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select :group_ids, current_user.company.groups.order(:name), :id, :name, {},
      { multiple: true } %>

    <%= f.label :user_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, current_user.company.users.order(:first_name), :id, :first_name, {},
    { multiple: true } %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>


  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just that companies is showing up twice as a field on the Question class, just change the has_many line at the bottom of the Question class to:

```
has_many :questionable_companies, through: :question_participants, 
                                  source: :questionable, source_type: 'Company'
```

If that works, great! Otherwise....

I don't know a lot about polymorphism, but from what I do know, here's what I think will work:

User, Group, and Company should have this line:

```
has_many :question_participants, as: questionable
```

Question should use scopes instead of the three lines you have. Try this:

```
has_many :questionable, through: :question_participants
```

Once you've gotten :questionable as a field on Question, then you can make scopes

```
scope :questionable_users, -> { where(questionable_type: :User) }
scope :questionable_groups, -> { where(questionable_type: :Group) }
scope :questionable_companies, -> { where(questionable_type: :Company) }
```

I put questionable_ before each scope just so that the Company associations wouldn't complain.

I forget exactly how scopes compare to a belongs_to but it's possible it may miss some functionality you want.